# Custom compiler flicker open then close

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Im working with the custom compiler from MSDN website. When I try to compile/run some test code (drag and drop to .exe), the console window opens then closes instead of staying open until I choose to close it. How do I keep it open?

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx#S8

**Program.cs**

```
if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            // Display title, reset cursor to normal, add space
            Console.WriteLine("Alt ver 1.0 (Alpha)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                Scanner scanner = null;
                using (TextReader input = File.OpenText(args[0]))
                {
                    scanner = new Scanner(input);
                }
                Parser parser = new Parser(scanner.Tokens);
                CodeGen codeGen = new CodeGen(parser.Result, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0]) + ".exe");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } //if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `Console.ReadLine();`
at the last inside the `try` block
try this

```
    if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                // Display title, reset cursor to normal, add space
                Console.WriteLine("Alt ver 1.0 (Alpha)");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    Scanner scanner = null;
                    using (TextReader input = File.OpenText(args[0]))
                    {
                        scanner = new Scanner(input);
                    }
                    Parser parser = new Parser(scanner.Tokens);
                    CodeGen codeGen = new CodeGen(parser.Result, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0]) + ".exe");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
finally
{
Console.Readkey();
}
            } //if
else
{
Console.WriteLine("no args");
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

EDIT:--- passing argument problem
i have made this program and it works perfectly as far as getting filename as arguments
please have a look

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var arg in args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arg);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO ARGS");
                var fileName = Console.ReadLine();
                Main(new string[] { fileName });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried it, but still the same results

Comment: i have edited my ans.. making sure the args is being passed correctly

Comment: ok the console stays up now, but instead of compiling my code, it displays "no args."

Comment: make sure the name of the file is being passed correctly.. or alternatively you can just fire up a console window and manually call your and providing args like this.. PROGRAM_NAME.exe FilePath/FileName

Comment: That displayed the file's complete path

Comment: YEAH - was supposed to do it.. this means that if you some how merge my code and urs you will get the correct result..i dont know how you are passing the args because that part of the code isnt given by you

Comment: Other than what you showed me for the Program.cs, all the code for CodeGen.cs, Parser.cs Scanner.cs and Ast.cs is exactly the same from the link above (updated). There is even a basic template that is SUPPOSE to run that's downloadable.